# What could be the application of fisher information in interferometers for let say phase estimation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, entropy, quantum-optics

Quantum metrology is the study of highly sensitive measurements of physical parameters using quantum theory. We know that fisher information quantify the amount of information observable carries about a parameter. How can we use fisher information in meteorology? Can you explain it in terms of phase estimation using interferometers.

Comment: Can you provide more detail, e.g. is phase estimation with noisy data typically done via a maximum likelihood analysis? The (observed) Fisher information is then just the inverse of the covariance matrix from the fit, so the info is implicitly used even if called a different name. There's another form of the Fisher information, though, which is an expectation value of the former for a given phase, so it could tell you something about your expected sensitivity for different values of the phase or other nuisance parameters.

Comment: did you mean to write "metrology", are you actually asking about meteorology applications?

Answer (score 1):

This is based on my question and answer to my own question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/545242/205673). The quantum Fisher information (QFI) provides a measure of how much a quantum state $|\Psi(\theta)\rangle$ changes with respect to some variable, for example, the phase accumulated during an interferometer, $\theta$. This provides a way to estimate the phase sensitivity of the interferometer, which is given by
$$\Delta\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{F_Q}},$$
where $F_Q$ is the QFI and for pure states can be written as
$$F_Q=4\left(\langle\Psi'|\Psi'\rangle-\left|\langle\Psi'|\Psi\rangle\right|^2\right),$$
where $|\Psi'\rangle=\tfrac{d}{d\theta}|\Psi\rangle$ and $|\Psi\rangle$ the output state of the interferometer.

The QFI is derived by maximising the classical Fisher information over all generalised measurements in quantum mechanics. This result then provides us with an optimised lower bound for the variance in the estimation of $\theta$ provided one uses a corresponding optimal measurement. The optimised measurement can be verified by using a phase estimation method such as the calculus of error propagation
$$\Delta\theta=\frac{\langle\Delta O\rangle}{\left|\frac{d\langle O\rangle}{d\theta}\right|},$$
where $\langle\Delta O\rangle$ is the standard deviation and $O$ some Hermitian operator normally describing a measurement, the measurement could be the population difference between the two output arms of the interferometer.

In short, the QFI gives you the potential sensitivity of the state to a phase shift, however, it does not give you the measurement procedure that can achieve it.